# How to use same code for two different jQuery events without repetition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to call same function on two different events, that is as explained in the given example below:

```
 // calling a function on keyup
 $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
 });

 // calling same function on click
 $('#cancel').click(function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
 });
```

Please note that, the above function does the same thing in both of the cases, I just have to call that function under different conditions.

Now my question is, can I set both of the events in the same line, so that I can avoid setting function twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare the function separately, then use it in both events.

```
var func_event = function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
};

$('#textarea').keyup(func_event);
$('#cancel').click(func_event);
```

Comment: yes this can be used as an alternative, but can i do something like as we do in if condition in php, if one of the condition get true then the action performed. Something just like if condition in php?... can you provide such kind of solution plzz?

Comment: @user3172176: No, you can't.

Comment: hmmm.. okkk thanks so much for your kind response.. i will go with the solution provided by you... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function:

```
 // calling a function on keyup
 $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
       exampleFunction();
 });

 // calling same function on click
 $('#cancel').click(function() {
       exampleFunction();
 });

 function exampleFunction(){

       var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
       var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

       $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
 }
```